# Painting problem in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an small appliction window , pops up when a tray icon clicks. Inside that i have provided context menu (windows form context menu), the problem is, whenever i rightclicks on form, the context menu is appearing but on disappearing of context menu, border of context menu still exists. As i minimises/closes and reopen every thing works fine again.

Any one has any idea why it is behaving like so?

Ravi Naik.

Answer (score 0):

Set DoubleBuffering to true on the form. This should sort the problem out.

**Unless** you are drawing the stuff yourself using a Graphics object? Are you?

If you are then look up [Double Buffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/double-buffered-graphics), you can find out about this at a few places, such as [Bob Powell](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811193726/http://bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.aspx) and [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12870/Don-t-Flicker-Double-Buffer).

If it doesn't and you want a quick hack to get around it, on the context menu collapse event you could call form.Refresh() but avoid this at **all** costs.

Comment: Yup, i got to know about the problem. I was using onpaint() for to draw border to panel so i was facing this problem now i got the solution and instead of panel I am using rectangle now... :)

Thanks for your reply brother...